# skip over a pattern in sed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

I wrote a correctly working `sed` script which replaces multiple spaces with single space between tokens (it skips lines with `#` or `//`) :

```
#!/bin/sed -f
/.*#/ !{
/\/\//n
# handle more than one space between tokens
s/\([^ ]\)\s\+/\1 /g
}
```

i run it on ubuntu like this: `./spaces.sed < spa.txt`

spa.txt:

```
/**      spa.txt      text
 date :      some date
 hih+jjhh   jgjg
 if   ( hjh>=hjhjh  )
y     **/
#   this is a comment
   //    this is a comment
lines     begins   here   ;
/****** this    line   is comment      ****/
some    more     lines
//    again comment
more     lines    words
   /**  again multi     line co
   mmment    it
comment     line
      follows   till    here**/
file    ends
```

now i want to add the functionality that script should skip over lines between a pattern (pattern can be distributed in multiple lines). This is the pattern: `/*` and `*/`

I tried many things but of no use:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
/.*#/ !{
/\/\*/,/\*\// {
        /\/\*/n #it skips successfully the /* line
        n #also skips next line
        /\*\// !{
        }
}
/\/\//n
# handle more than one space between tokens
s/\([^ ]\)\s\+/\1 /g
}
```

but script isn't working as expected.

Expected output:

```
/**      spa.txt      text
 date :      some date
 hih+jjhh   jgjg
 if   ( hjh>=hjhjh  )
y     **/
#   this is a comment
   //    this is a comment
lines begins here ;
/****** this    line   is comment      ****/
some more lines
//    again comment
more lines words
   /**  again multi     line co
   mmment    it
comment     line
      follows   till    here**/
file ends
```

suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd re-engineer the script a bit, to handle `#` and `//` comments on their own.  With the `/* … */` comments, you have to deal with single-line and multi-line variants separately.  I'd also use the `[[:space:]]` notation to spot spaces or tabs.  I prefer to avoid backslashes (an aversion caused by working with `troff` in the days of my youth — if you've never needed 16 backslashes in a row to get the desired effect, you've not suffered enough), so I use `\%…%` to choose the `%` character as the search marker instead of `/` (which means there's no need to escape the slashes in the pattern with a backslash), and I use `[*]` instead of `\*`. The `{ p; d; }` notation prints the current line and then deletes it and moves onto the next line.  (Using `n` appends the next line to the current line; it isn't what you need.). The second semicolon isn't required by GNU `sed` but is by BSD (macOS) `sed`.  The spaces in those braces are optional but make it easier to read.

Putting this together, you might have `spaces.sed` like this:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# Comments with a #
/#/ { p; d; }
# Comments with //
\%//% { p; d; }

# Single line /* ... */ comments
\%/[*].*[*]/% { p; d; }
# Multi-line /* ... */ comments
\%/[*]%,\%[*]/% { p; d; }

s/\([^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]\{2,\}/\1 /g
```

On your sample data (thanks for including it!), this produces:

```
/**      spa.txt      text
 date :      some date
 hih+jjhh   jgjg
 if   ( hjh>=hjhjh  )
y     **/
#   this is a comment
   //    this is a comment
lines begins here ;
/****** this    line   is comment      ****/
some more lines
//    again comment
more lines words
   /**  again multi     line co
   mmment    it
comment     line
      follows   till    here**/
file ends
```

That looks like what you wanted.

#### Limitations

- It doesn't remove multiple spaces at the start of a line.

  ```
          the leading blanks are not removed.
  ```
- If you have a line with multiple spaces and `//` or `#`, the multiple spaces remain:

  ```
  these     spaces    // survive
  so        do        # these
  ```
- If you have multiple single line comments on a single line, you don't get spaces removed in between them:

  ```
  /* these */  spaces  are   not   /* removed */
  ```
- If you have a single-line comment and the start of a multi-line comment on a single line, the multi-line comment is not spotted.  Similarly, if you have a multi-line comment that ends on a line and has a single-line comment starting after it, then if there are any multiple spaces between the end of the one comment and the start of the next, they are not handled.

  ```
  /* this */  is  not  /* handled
  very  well  */    nor   are   these   /* spaces */
  ```
- This doesn't deal with the subtleties of backslash-newline in the middle of a start or end comment symbol, nor with backslash-newline at the end of a `//` comment.  Only brain-dead programs (or programmers) produce such comments, so it shouldn't be a real problem.  Fortunately, you're not writing a compiler; those have to deal with the nonsense.  And don't get me started on trigraphs!
- It doesn't handle comment-like sequences inside strings (or multi-character character constants):

  ```
  "/* this is not a comment */"
  '/*',   '  ',   '*/'
  ```

However, most of these issues are subtle enough that you're probably OK without dealing with them.  If you must deal with them, then you need a program, not a `sed` script (assuming you value your sanity).

Comment: Thanks alot Jonathan, this is exactly what i wanted. thanks alot.

Comment: +1 for this very good answer and careful explanations. Never thought of using `[*]` instead of `\*` but indeed it looks more readable to me too. I have two notes: `{ p; d; }` could be simplified with just `b` (branch to next cycle) and the capture in the `s` command could be removed, making it simpler and also catching multiple spaces at the start of a line.

Comment: @luciole75w: Good suggestions — thank you.  On the space-removing `s///`, I'll plead guilty to taking what was in the question and tinkering instead of rethinking it from scratch.